# pyparsing.ParseException: Expected "File path :", found 'ÿ'

Tags: pyparsing

I am trying to extract file path from a TXT file using pyparsing.

The file path is like this

```
 File path :         C:\user\1\book
```

Part of My code is:

```
file_path = (
    Literal('File path :').suppress() +
    Word(printables).setResultsName('file_path') +
    LineEnd().suppress()
)
```

After I run the code, there is an exception. I'm not what it is.

```
pyparsing.ParseException: Expected "File path :", found 'ÿ'  (at char 0), (line:1, col:1)
```

How can I fix that?

Comment: Assuming you are running `print(file_path.parseString(text_string))`, try first doing `print(repr(text_string))`. I suspect you are reading from a file that has an embedded byte-order marker, which looks like `ÿþ` (`\xfe\xff`). Either save your text to a file without this BOM, or do `text_string = text_string.lstrip("\xfe\xff")` from your text before parsing.

Comment: If reading from a file, you can also use an encoding that will strip this off for you. More info here: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/unicode.html#reading-and-writing-unicode-data

Comment: @PaulMcG Thank you. I tried to use this to read file --- `with open("data/examples.TXT", "r", encoding="utf-16") as f:
    content=f.readlines() `--- then `parseFile(content).asDict()`. I got this error: TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not list. How can I convert the file as the string or convert to  a plain txt?

Comment: `readlines()` will return a list of the separate lines of text from the file. `read()` will give the whole file contents as a single string, which I think is what you want. So use `content_str = content.read()` to get the file contents as a single string, then use `results = file_path.parseString(content_str)`. From there you can work with the returned results, convert to dict, etc. (Try `results.pprint()` or `print(results.dump())` for some insights on what you have gotten.)